# Spring + Hibernate populating holder class with values from DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

For my web app I will loading a few details from the static DB tables which I plan to load when the container starts up on a HolderClass in a singleton bean. I will inject this class wherever I wish to use the static data. So basically I want to avoid loading the static data everytime from DB

Current Implementation:

```
public Class CountryHolder(){
    List<Country> allCountries;

    public void init(){
       this.countries = loadAllCountries;
    }

    public List<Country> loadAllCountries(){
     // Perform DB select query using JDBC template
    }
```

The above implementation works perfectly fine that is the init method loads the list of Countries for my bean. But now I have migrated to Hibernate and Country is a Persisten Entity.

Hibernate:

```
@Transactional(readOnly ="true")
public List<Country> loadAllCountries(){
   return countryDao.findAll();
}
```

Please note I have skipped the code where I am injecting the dao and jdbc template. But the issue is that since I am calling this method in init method Hibernate complains about no session found to this although I have declared it as a readOnly transaction.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since Spring doesn't do persistence itself, it cannot specify what readOnly should exactly mean. This attribute is only a hint to the provider, the behavior depends on, in this case, Hibernate.

If you specify readOnly as true, the flush mode will be set as `FlushMode.NEVER` in the current Hibernate Session preventing the session from commiting the transaction.

Furthermore, `setReadOnly(true)` will be called on the JDBC Connection, which is also a hint to the underlying database. If your database supports it (most likely it does), this has basically the same effect as FlushMode.NEVER, but it's stronger since you cannot even flush manually.

It will be more **helpful if you post `Hibernate context`?**

**Updated**

What you think about using `ApplicationContext` or `DI`

My idea to use an `bean class` which will be get loaded at the time of spring container is loading.In that `bean class` you will connect to DB fetch records and use where you want to use without going to DB each time.

I am doing this in  my project where I am fetching some Menus from DB when server context get loaded and use it without roundTriping to DB each time.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not get what you are suggesting? What should I be doing to get it to work?

Comment: @Pratik For `HibernateTransactionManager` have you created any bean config using the class `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`?

Comment: Yes I have the necessary mappings in place. I am able to use the transactionManager in other classes. I skipped all that code and I have mentioned the same in the note. Please be assured that the Hibernate Configuration are correct. The issue is since its in init method the session is not found. I need to know if anyone has loaded such holder objects from DB using some different approach.

Comment: Can you plz try after adding above part in web.xml.

Comment: Open session in View will enable to have a session throughout the request. But what I need is to populate these holder class when spring container is initiated. So that I do not have to call these queries on every request.

Comment: @Pratik use of `DI` is very useful is such case.plz Try.

Comment: I am using DI but I wish to inject values from DB when the bean is instantiated. At that time there is no Hibernate session bound. How do i overcome that

Comment: @Pratik Will you please post/update with `web.xml`? Because in my POC project I am able to get Hibernate session and do necessary work on it. I am not getting any hibernate session not found error.

Comment: are you calling the dao classes while instantiating the bean. Are you using it in the init method of the bean. I tried the init method, postconstruct and postinitialize as well and it did not work. I cannot post the entire web.xml sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay then I will just post what I did to load Masters from DB on server context loading.

**HibernateHelper.java**

```
public final class HibernateHelper 
{
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static 
{
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml)
        // config file.

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistry sr = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties)).buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory tempSessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(sr);
        sessionFactory = tempSessionFactory;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
}


public Session getSession() 
{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
{
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

*HibernateHelper class will help to `buildSessionFactory` by reading `hibernate.cfg.xml`.This class having `getSession()which return`session`*.

**HibernateHelper_DI.xml**

```
<bean id="Hhelper" class="util.HibernateHelper" />
```

*An DI xml file which is responsible for creating singalton bean of HibernateHelper.*

**MasterHelper.java**

```
public final class MasterHelper implements ApplicationContextAware 
{
       private static getMasterServiceImpl runtimeServiceImpl;
       private static List<Master> masters=null;

       public static List<Master> getMasters()
       {
         if(masters==null)
         {
          loadMasters();
         }
         return masters;
       }

       private static void loadMasters()
       {
          try
          {      
             if(masters==null){      
            masters=runtimeServiceImpl.getMasters();            
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
           masters=null;
           throw e;
          }    
       }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
                throws BeansException {

            runtimeServiceImpl= (getMasterServiceImpl) applicationContext
                    .getBean("getMasterService");
         }   


}
```

**getMasterService_DI.xml**

```
<bean id="getMasterService" class="service.getMasterServiceImpl" />
```

*An DI xml file which is responsible for creating singalton bean of getMasterServiceImpl.*

**MasterHelper_DI.xml**

```
<bean id="MasterHelper" class="service.MasterHelper" />
```

*An DI xml file which is responsible for creating singalton bean of MasterHelper.*

**By this config. spring knows from where DI files is get read.**

**root-context.xml**

```
<import resource="classpath:DI/*.xml" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When context loading is going on, with the help of `web.xml` and `root-context.xml` spring reads DI files and make beans accordingly.

When `HibernateHelper` bean is created `sessionfactory` is also created and kept in static object.In the same fashion when `MasterHelper` bean is created.

When you call `MasterHelper.getMasters();` for the first time anywhere in web application it will goes to DB load the masters and assign to static `masters`.Next time when you call `MasterHelper.getMasters();` it will check for null condition to static `master`.

if you want at the time of bean creation you want to load masters then you can use change method `setApplicationContext()` in MasterHelper as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {

        runtimeServiceImpl= (getMasterServiceImpl) applicationContext
                .getBean("getMasterService");
                loadMasters(); //IMPOTANT TO CALL HERE ONLY,BCOZ loadMasters NEED BEAN OF       getMasterServiceImpl
     }
```

Hope This will help you.

**All above code is written manually at here only so there may be some syntax error(s) are there, please correct if any found**

Comment: Thanks amogh...really appreciate. I will be off work for 3 days and will surely try to implement this on thursday and update you with the same. Thanks once again