# Hibernate-Mysql exception on a read loop

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got this exception during a select "get" query loop.
Can you tell me how to avoid this?

```
2014-01-21 18:54:36 [WARN]SqlExceptionHelper:143    SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2014-01-21 18:54:36 [ERROR]SqlExceptionHelper:144   Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:399)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.cinebot.db.Dao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7e1b7d44.getIngresso(<generated>)
    at com.cinebot.service.LogAnalyzerService.processLogFile(LogAnalyzerService.java:273)
    at com.cinebot.service.LogAnalyzerService.check(LogAnalyzerService.java:119)
    at com.cinebot.service.LogAnalyzerThreadService$AnalisiLog.run(LogAnalyzerThreadService.java:55)
    at com.cinebot.thread.StatusThreadStep.doStep(StatusThreadStep.java:91)
    at com.cinebot.thread.ThreadAbstractService.process(ThreadAbstractService.java:57)
    at com.cinebot.service.LogAnalyzerThreadService.run(LogAnalyzerThreadService.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

I found that there was just one connection during this exception.
This is the Dao:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
public <T> T get(Class<T> classe, Serializable id) throws Exception {
    if(id==null) return null;
    T obj = (T) getSession().get(classe, id);
    return obj;
}
```

This is app configuration:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.cin.web.DataSourceSelector" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.cin.db.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>             
                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">always</prop>               
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
...
```

This is the database selector:

```
public class DataSourceSelector extends DriverManagerDataSource {

    private String catalog;
    private static Logger logss = Logger.getLogger(DataSourceSelector.class);

    public String getCatalog(){
        return catalog;
    }

    public DataSourceSelector(){
        super();
        String adb=DbConnector.getActiveDb();
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(adb)){                  
            setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            catalog=adb;
            setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+catalog);
            logss.info("Selezionato DB: "+catalog);
            setUsername("cin_java");
            setPassword("password");
        }
    }

}
```

And the query loop is very simple and has something like this called >20000 times

```
dao.get(Entitiy.call,id)
```

I tried to add session.flush() session.clear() but I still get that error after 16000 query.

Comment: have you implemented connection pooling?Can you check how many connectons are ther in mysql server?

Comment: No, there is just a org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean inside a Spring web app

Comment: can you post code block?

Comment: Can be related with hibernate.connection.release_mode? What is its default behaviour of relese?

Comment: Seems something that fills the session memory, I also tried to slow down the process with a thread.sleep but the process stops at the same point. Is it possibile to force to restart hibernate session?

Comment: No there no such method which will Restart session as per my knowledge. if you have and if there are some open sessions then how you can close that session?

Comment: Can you try to implement connection pooling?In my case pooling solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

By your updated post I analyse that may be hibernate not releasing database connections after returning result. Because of which DB server getting into huge load.

I will suggest :

-Use `session.flush();` and `session.clear()` after `session.get(Entity.class, id);`

-As you set you are doing `session.get(Entity.class, id);` in loop check you are not creating SessionFactory everytime.Implement an class which provide an static SessionFactory.

-Try to implement connection pooling with [`c3p0`](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) or any think else.

**Update**(Related to class which provide an static SessionFactory)

When you do any transaction/operation with DB using hibernate you will need an `session` this `session` is responsible for DB state,operation (CRUD). You will get session from an `SessionFactory` which is created by reading hibernate configuration like `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

To build sessionFactory we use `SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();` if you call this code in a loop then this will trouble you more.

My idea is to create an class which will have `static SessionFactory` which will get created at the time of spring context loading using `DI`.

plz got to  [My answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131746/spring-hibernate-populating-holder-class-with-values-from-db#21201338) where i post code for **HibernateHelper.java** with **HibernateHelper_DI.xml** which will create static sessionFactory at the time of context loading.

When you need an `session` from sessionFactory you will just call:

```
Session session = HibernateHelper.getSession();
//work with session
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

`buildSessionFactory();` is deprecated in Hibernate 4 now we have to use `buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)` you can find new method in `HibernateHelper`.

Comment: Connection pooling using `c3p0` and some code audit solved my `maximum connections reached?` problem.

Comment: thanks for you answer.  can you explain a bit more the second suggestion?

Comment: A bit of information is updtaed to answer please check and correct me if i m wrong somewhere.

Comment: I update my question with more about getSession() method. I tried with you first 2 suggestion but I did not solve. My sessionbuilder is already static (I check it logging da object for each query) using hibernate's LocalSessionFactoryBean.

Comment: It's getting difficult to reflect problem at my side,I am using my class to manage static sessionFactory and called `session(Person.class,i)` where `i` is my loop verable I am having 60k+ records in DB and I started loop with `i=1;i<=50000` but my side all is working fine.

Comment: As per last update in method `get(Class<T> classe, Serializable id)` `session.flush()` and `session.clear()` is not used. The same method you are calling in loop right?

Comment: I tried to append inside the loop getSession().flush()  and getSession().clear(), but still doesn't work. Moreover i have this hibernate property: <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">always</prop>

Comment: @Tobia Any progress ahead?

Comment: I decided to use a standard JDBC connection. This is much faster. Regarding my question about Hibernate trouble, I have no solution for now.